# Getting Ansible runtime error dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines' despite variable not null

Tags: ansible, runtime-error, pid

Below is my playbook which has a variable `running_processes` which contains a list of pids(one or more)

Next, I read the user ids for each of the pids. All good so far.

I then try to print the list of user ids in `curr_user_ids` variable using `-debug module` is when i get the error: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'

I was expecting the `curr_user_ids` to contain one or more entries as evident from the output shared below.

```
    - name: Get running processes list from remote host
      shell: "ps -few | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'"
      changed_when: false
      register: running_processes

    - name: Gather USER IDs from processes id before killing.
      shell: "id -nu `cat /proc/{{ running_processes.stdout }}/loginuid`"
      register: curr_user_ids
      with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"

    - debug: msg="USER ID LIST HERE:{{ curr_user_ids.stdout }}"
      with_items: "{{ curr_user_ids.stdout_lines }}"

TASK [Get running processes list from remote host] **********************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/wls/startstop.yml:22
ok: [10.9.9.111] => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "cmd": "ps -few | grep java | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}'", "delta": "0:00:00.166049", "end": "2019-11-06 11:49:42.298603", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-11-06 11:49:42.132554", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "24032", "stdout_lines": ["24032"]}

TASK [Gather USER IDS of processes id before killing.] ******************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/wls/startstop.yml:59
changed: [10.9.9.111] => (item=24032) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "id -nu `cat /proc/24032/loginuid`", "delta": "0:00:00.116639", "end": "2019-11-06 11:46:41.205843", "item": "24032", "rc": 0, "start": "2019-11-06 11:46:41.089204", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "user1", "stdout_lines": ["user1"]}

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/wls/startstop.yml:68
fatal: [10.9.9.111]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"}
```

Can you please suggest why am I getting the error and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Few points to note why your solution didn't work.

The task `Get running processes list from remote host` returns a newline splitted `\n` string. So you will need to process this and turn the output into a propper list object first.

The task `Gather USER IDs from processes id before killing.` is returning a dictionary containing the key `results` where the value is of type list, so you will need iterate over it and fetch for each element the `stdout` value.

This is how I solved it.

```
---

- hosts: "localhost"
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
      - name: Set default values
        set_fact:
          process_ids: []
          user_names: []

      - name: Get running processes list from remote host
        shell: "ps -few | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'"
        changed_when: false
        register: running_processes

      - name: Register a list of Process ids (Split newline from output before)
        set_fact:
          process_ids: "{{ running_processes.stdout.split('\n') }}"

      - name: Gather USER IDs from processes id before killing.
        shell: "id -nu `cat /proc/{{ item }}/loginuid`"
        register: curr_user_ids
        with_items: "{{ process_ids }}"

      - name: Register a list of User names (Out of result from before)
        set_fact:
          user_names: "{{ user_names + [item.stdout] | unique }}"
        when: item.rc == 0
        with_items:
          - "{{ curr_user_ids.results }}"

      - name: Set unique entries in User names list
        set_fact:
          user_names: "{{ user_names | unique }}"

      - name: DEBUG
        debug:
          msg: "{{ user_names }}"
```

Comment: incase there are no processes running the curr_user_ids.results  throws error  dict object has no attribute 'results'. Can you suggest how can we avoid that error when the results are empty?

Comment: You can verify the exit code of the shell execution and only add user name to `user_names` when the previous command succeeded, hence the rc code is 0. You could add `when: item.rc == 0` to the task named `Register a list of User names (Out of result from before)`.

Comment: What about commands like ls -ltr will always return item.rc as 0. It may yield zero or more results. How do we check if it returns nothing as output.

Answer (score 0):

The variable *curr_user_ids* registers results of each iteration

```
register: curr_user_ids
with_items: "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
```

The list of the results is stored in

```
curr_user_ids.results
```

Take a look at the variable

```
- debug:
    var: curr_user_ids
```

and loop the stdout_lines

```
- debug:
    var: item.stdout_lines
  loop: "{{ curr_user_ids.results }}"
```